# Can Joomla search Custom HTML Modules?

Tags: html, css, search, joomla, module

Can the Joomla search function search through Custom HTML Modules? Anytime I enter a keyword in my search box, it only returns results from Categories, Contacts, Articles, Newsfeeds, and Weblinks. However, most of my website content is on these custom modules. Sorry, I'm new at Joomla and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: An interesting way to make this work is to use articles as modules.I.e this module (http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/content-embed/17813) allows to load article in module. So if you will search something in module, you will automatically get results from articles. (which you loaded in module).

Answer (score 3):

It wouldn't really make sense because how would you return the results? Modules do not have urls to link to.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box this feature is not implemented and I don't know of any extensions which do that. However, you could write your own search plugin: http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin_Development

Regards